# Best PCB layout for this circuit to minimize noise at the output

Tags: noise

This circuit contains the final stages of my home built spectrum analyzer.  The design is based on the classic Wes Hayward circuit with a few modern improvements, all of which are online.  I've built a Gen#1 version (minus the '3904 pre-amp) that works well but has too high quiescent noise with no input signal.  So I am considering building a Gen#2 lay-out to reduce that quiescent noise.

I don't think the enclosure construction of my Gen#1 is the culprit, it uses a Hammond aluminum box with 1nF feed-thru caps and RG316 coax from the PCB to the connectors.  So I am looking at making this 2nd spin of the PCB to try and lower the noise.

[image: Gen#2 Schematic]

Basic operation is a 10.7MHz signal at about -35dBm max enters the '2904 pre-amp for about 8dB gain, the AD603 is used as a user adjustable variable gain amp (appx 0dB to 40dB), which feeds a 10.7MHz/180kHz wide Murata ceramic filter, then the AD8307 log amp, and finally a 4.2x gain CA3140 to boost the output to drive the Y-axis of a 'scope.

Schematic from the AD603 to the AD8307 is lifted almost verbatim (minus the AGC loop) from AD's application guide.

Here's the present state of my Gen#2 layout:

[image: Gen2 layout]

Both the Gen1 and Gen2 layouts are 2-sided PCB with a continuous ground plane underneath.  The major differences between them is the Gen1 was about 2x as large and used a mix of thru-hole and SMT components, Gen2 is almost all SMT.  I also moved all ground plane via connections to much closer to their respective components (exception: I made a local star ground for the output of the AD603 and input of the AD8307 to a common via to the ground plane, based on AD's recommendation).

Are there any other best practices I should incorporate?  Searching the internet for best RF practices turns up a lot of stuff, some of it contradictory, some of it likely just lore with no scientific basis.

Here is the Gen1 circuit diagram.  It does not have the '3904 preamp, it uses different voltage regulators, and the filter between the AD603 and AD8307 is made from discrete LC components.

[image: Gen1 schematic]

And here is the Gen1 layout. I mis-spoke above, my Gen1 construction had nearly solid ground plane on bottom (clearances for thru-hole parts) and ground pour on top with a few hand made vias.

[image]

Comment: Where are the feedthrough caps ? 2-layer board had which thickness? Can you provide the old layout instead of new one (the one which had problems)

Comment: What’s the noise spectrum and noise figure?

Comment: Thanks, I edited the post to add the Gen1 schematic and layout.  Regarding noise spectrum and noise figure - I'm not sure how to answer that fully.  The noise I am referring to is the effective noise floor of the entire spectrum analyzer, it is the magnitude of the RMS output of the entire circuit being higher than I see from others who have built this design.  Sorry for the vague answer, EE is not my day job...

Comment: Also the 1nF feed thru caps protrude through the wall of the Hammond box, a short jumper wire connects the inside terminal to the PCB which is 1.6mm thick.